# V2.79 - What are the new numpad keyboard shortcuts for changing camera view?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut

In the last version blender I used (2.69 maybe?) the numpad allowed me to switch between user, ortho / perspective, top, bottom, back, front, left, and right views.

At the moment the only ones that seem to do close to what I expect are:

- numpad 3 = right ortho
- ctrl + (numpad 1) = back ortho

the rest just seem to (mostly) flip into arbitrary views or rotate the camera in small increments.

Incidentally I chose the "3DS Max" input settings in user preferences if that's likely to have made it go odd...

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open User Preferences
2. Navigate to Input tab and change the keyboard preset back to Blender.
   [image]

Also, you can select the preset directly from splash screen:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - you just told me how to switch to "blender" defaults which isn't what I want.

In the previous version I had installed I literally installed blender, chose "3DS Max" defaults and it worked as I described.

I like the mouse buttons like 3DSMax.

This didn't start working for me in the version of blender I mentioned until AFTER I loaded factory settings.

Comment: doesnt answer the question, not sure why this has any upvotes

Answer (score -1):

ok. super weird.

Out of frustration I chose "Load factory settings" and now it all works how I expected.

Comment: that is not really weird. the "factory settings" will have the blender key map, not the 3Ds max one.

Comment: technically this isn't an anwer to the question either